# Best way to Standardize street addresses in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, regex, string, mariadb

I have a db table column full of street addresses.  Long story short I need to standardize all the the streets to their abbreviated versions.
For Example
street = St. etc.

etc.

The catch is the table is over 10,000+ records with any number of combinations of abbreviated/non-abbreviated street versions.  IS there a more efficient way than as follows:

```
UPDATE hospital
set tiger_address = replace(street, 'Street', 'St')
;

UPDATE hospital
set tiger_address = replace(street, 'street', 'St')
;
```

Ideally Id like one query for each street type.  I also have to do directionals as well (N,S,E,W,etc)

Just looking to tackle each street type (road, boulevard, etc) in one query.  And yes I Know using 'street' as a column title is more confusing but I didn't design the table.

Looked into `regexp` and `soundex` but admittedly I'm rusty on my sql stored functions.

PS - will mark as both MYsql and MariaDB but I work off the latest MariaDB release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regexp is not the solution here and I wouldn't trust soundex to do a correct job 100% of the time.

Your only choice I see in stacking the functions, so that you only have to update the table once.

```
UPDATE hospital
set tiger_address = replace(replace(replace(street, 'Street', 'St'), 'street', 'St'), 'boulevard', 'Blvd')
;
```